# how to make two column layout using flexbox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make two column layout using `display: flex`. I want to show two column with equal `width` and `height` (max height which have more content).

Here is my code.
https://jsbin.com/wataripuzu/edit?html,output

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="row">
  <div class="left">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
  <div>22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set `word-break: break-all` because those numbers are considered as one long word and by default will stay in one line.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row > div {
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="row">
  <div class="left">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
  <div>22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</div>
</section>
```